# Firebase: Database + Storage - best practice of referencing the correct image of a post | Vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

- Vue.JS
- Vuex
- firebase / firestore

I have created a website where you can submit **text** and an **image** for your post.
Currently I am giving the `post.postPicture` the **entire** URL of the image that belongs to it. That works.

The images are stored in the firebase storage under `/$useruid/$filename`.

Now, as it is prone to happen, what if the `filename` or `userid` changes? (assuming i don't fix the path)
What is the best practice of referencing the image that belongs to the post?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to use data that changes in the path of a document.  Avoid that.

It's not clear to me what your `userid` is exactly.  User IDs issued by Firebase Authentication should never change.  If you're using some sort of screen name that the user can change, that should not be used in the path.  You should instead assign each user a unique, unchanging ID, and store their screen name in a separate document attached to that ID.

It's also not clear to me what exactly your `filename` is.  But the same principle applies - if it can be changed, then it shouldn't be part of a document path.  Generate a random ID and put the file name in a field in a document associated with that ID.

This sort of modeling with random IDs is the whole reason why operations like add() exist in Firestore.  add() will generate that random ID for you, and you populate the document with data that helps you find it later.  Read more in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document).

Comment: This is actually quite helpful. However what my main question is, is it a bad habit to save the entire filepath of the image in the post object?

Comment: I don't really know what you're asking.  Save whatever data will be helpful when you query the document later.